# When is a stack object within a function call constructed?

Tags: c++, stack, object-construction

Say I have a simple function:

```
void foo(int val) {
    if(val == 0) {
       return;
    }
    else {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "Hello World" << endl << ends;
      cout << ss.str();
   }
}
```

If I call the function with `val == 0`, does the stringstream object ss ever get constructed?  I suspect no, but just want to confirm.

Comment: No, `ss` does not get constructed as it is in a different scope that is never entered.

Comment: It's easy to tell: just put a class you wrote instead of `stringstream` (extend `stringstream` for example) and let its constructor and destructor output some messages. You can find out this way the exact moment when each object is created and destructed.

Comment: @axiac, that's a clever trick.  I'll try that next time I want to see if an object gets constructed.

Comment: @PentiumPro200 _"that's a clever trick"_ Well, the simplest approaches are often the most clever ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely how scopes in C/C++ are useful: to not construct objects that you don't want to be constructed.

Here, your `stringstream` object shall only be constructed if you penetrate in its scope, defined by `else` curly brackets.

So no, your object won't be constructed if `val == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the program won't run to this point, this stringstream won't be constructed.